# ADF how to convert column name to attribute anme

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am new to ADF ,now I get the column Name of table just like USER_NAME ,in the ADF EO VO the 
attibute name will be converted to another pattern like UserName，but the attribute name can change to any name the user want ,So is there any method which can get the  attribute name of VO according to the column name?

Answer (score 0):

You go to the VO.xml property and set hints. Navigate to the overview section and select the attribute and goto edit. Set a hint which in this case would be the label. On the ui you would access it as :

```
label=#{bindings.sampleAttribute.hints.label}
```