# oracle ADF related query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf

there is one search page in ORACLE ADF with header & line section ... in header section i search for the customer id (i can also search with any column name like customer name , organization id etc) then in line section it will show me all the customer related to that customer id now in line section i make that customer id a hyperlink and as user click on that link (customer id) it will show a popup contain all the details related to that customer (around 700 column)..column names are like column 1,column 2,column3 ....column 700 like that and the name of this column 1 ,column 2 up-to column 700 is stored in some other table so how can i change that column1 ,column2 ...column 700 with their actual name (which is stored in some different table ).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might trey is to Query the other table using this:[How can I get column names from a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-oracle) to get the column names and then use the VO api to change the hint for the column: [ADF how to convert column name to attribute anme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749824/adf-how-to-convert-column-name-to-attribute-anme)

Answer (score 0):

You use two VOs in the page.
VO1 fetches column names, the other VO2 fetches column values.
Create a Form based on VO2, then go to each column and update the label attribute for that column to point to the right value from VO1.